# (Debian) cold boot from SD card fails

Tags: linux, boot, debian, crash, sd-card

I have an ION/Atom board that i want to boot from a SD card inserted in a reader which is connected via USB. The reader is built into the frontpanel of the machine's case and it's connected directly to the mainboard.

I've installed debian squeeze directly to the SD card by using a netinst image. The installation went fine and i was able to reboot a number of times - until i shut down the machine for a few hours.

Now i have a problem booting the machine. A cold-boot won't work. The boot process fails randomly at any stage after loading GRUB. Everytime i try to monitor the boot process, the kernel & initrd load fine and init bails out at some point (most times when it comes to executing getty). But the errors vary.

After a few tries (mostly 2) the machine boots fine and i can't reproduce the problem anymore, until i shut down the machine and wait a while.

I tried two different SD cards. None of them worked. The cards are just fine! I also cloned the installation to an USB stick from which i can boot just fine. With the stick it doesn't matter if the machine was running before or not.

**Question(s):**
Is there something i have to consider when booting off a SD card? Does anyone else have the same problems?

I read about a few guys having problems like these with uBoot on a Sheevaplug (which i own, too. but it works fine). Any Ideas?

Comment: Hardware fault on the part of the SD reader...? I don't know why you want to use SD, if USB works fine.

Comment: Hardware is new and - as far as i can see - it works just fine.